# using redux-observable epics to decorate data through multiple actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm struggling with [`redux-observable`](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable), trying to figure out how to create an epic with this flow:

1. listen for a `GET_ITEMS_REQUEST` action
2. send an HTTP request to get some items
3. grab the IDs of those items and dispatch a `GET_ITEM_DETAILS_REQUEST` action, which will send another HTTP request to get some more details for those items
4. decorate the items from the first request with the details from the second request and dispatch a final `GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS` action, which will update the redux state

Going from step 3 to 4 is where I'm stuck. I know how to dispatch `GET_ITEM_DETAILS_REQUEST` with the item IDs, but I don't know how to listen/subscribe to the `GET_ITEM_DETAILS_REQUEST` action to get the item details response.

So far, I have the following:

```
function getItemsEpic(action$) {

  return action$
    // step 1
    .ofType('GET_ITEMS_REQUEST')
    .mergeMap(() => {
      // step 2
      return Observable.from(Api.getItems())
    })
    .mergeMap((items) => {
      // step 3
      const itemIds = items.map((item) => item.id);
      return Observable.of({
        type: 'GET_ITEM_DETAILS_REQUEST',
        ids: itemIds
      });
    })
    // ... what now?
    .catch(() => {
      return Observable.of({
        type: 'GET_ITEMS_FAILURE'
      });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is, after you received the items, start listening for `GET_ITEM_DETAILS_FULFILLED` and then immediately kick off `GET_ITEM_DETAILS_REQUEST` using `startWith()`. The other epic will look the details up and emit `GET_ITEM_DETAILS_FULFILLED` which our other epic is patiently waiting for and then will zip the two (items + details) together.

```js
const getItemDetailsEpic = action$ =>
  action$
    .ofType('GET_ITEM_DETAILS_REQUEST')
    .mergeMap(({ ids }) =>
      Observable.from(Api.getItemDetails(ids))
        .map(details => ({
          type: 'GET_ITEM_DETAILS_FULFILLED',
          details
        }))
    );

const getItemsEpic = action$ =>
  action$
    .ofType('GET_ITEMS_REQUEST')
    .mergeMap(() =>
      Observable.from(Api.getItems())
        .mergeMap(items =>
          action$.ofType('GET_ITEM_DETAILS_FULFILLED')
            .take(1) // don't listen forever! IMPORTANT!
            .map(({ details }) => ({
              type: 'GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS',
              items: items.map((item, i) => ({
                ...item,
                detail: details[i]
                // or the more "safe" `details.find(detail => detail.id === item.id)`
                // if your data structure allows. Might not be necessary if the
                // order is guaranteed to be the same
              }))
            }))
            .startWith({
              type: 'GET_ITEM_DETAILS_REQUEST',
              ids: items.map(item => item.id)
            })
        )
    );
```

Separately, I noticed you put your `catch()` on the outer Observable chain. This is probably not going to do entirely what you want. By the time the error reaches the top chain, your entire epic will have been terminated--it will no longer be listening for future `GET_ITEMS_REQUEST`! This is a very important distinction and we often call it "isolating your Observable chains". You don't want errors to propagate further than they should.

```js
// GOOD
const somethingEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType('SOMETHING')
    .mergeMap(() =>
      somethingThatMayFail()
        .catch(e => Observable.of({
          type: 'STUFF_BROKE_YO',
          payload: e,
          error: true
        }))
    );

// NOT THE SAME THING!
const somethingEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType('SOMETHING')
    .mergeMap(() =>
      somethingThatMayFail()
    )
    .catch(e => Observable.of({
      type: 'STUFF_BROKE_YO',
      payload: e,
      error: true
    }));
```

You sometimes do want a catch on the outer chain, but that's a last ditch thing usually only for errors that are not recoverable.

Comment: I made an important change: I forgot to add `take(1)` after the `action$.ofType('GET_ITEM_DETAILS_FULFILLED')`. This is important because otherwise your epic will forever be listening to them and with the `mergeMap` will indefinitely accumulate more and more of them.

Comment: This looks great, thanks! What guarantees that `GET_ITEM_DETAILS_FULFILLED` will be exactly the response for the details request that was immediately sent? What if there's another `GET_ITEM_DETAILS_FULFILLED` emitted before the details request comes back with a response?

Comment: By the way, thanks for the note on the `catch()`. I've been struggling with that as well.

Comment: also, does the order of `take(1).map(...).startWith(...)` matter?

Comment: also, shouldn't `.map(({ details }) => ({` actually be `mergeMap`? after trying it locally, using `.map()` throws the `Actions must be plain objects` error, and `mergeMap()` seems to work correctly.

Comment: If you need concurrent, overlapping requests, you'll need to filter them out by some identifier, e.g. item id to the one you're the epic is currently looking for within the mergeMap.

Comment: The order of operators *always* is meaningful but sometimes has the same end result--I think it's important to clarify distinction compared to "order doesn't matter". In this case, the startWith *definitely* should be last otherwise you'll map against that value (not what you want) and the take(1) needs to be atleast before the startWith, but for clarity it's best to place it as close to the source you want to take 1 from as possible.

Comment: My `.map(({ details })` is what I intended. It appears to work for me so perhaps your code has differences than mine? http://jsbin.com/vekobok/edit?js,console